# Airflow webserver terminate because of wrong app context Flask

Tags: python, flask, airflow

So I had Airflow's webserver running fine until I created a Flask app within the same project root.

```
project/
  |
  -airflow_home/ # airflow dags, config, etc...
  |
  -app/
    |
    -__init__.py
    -models.py
    -config.py
    -routes.py
  |
  -manage.py
```

here is the airflow-webserver error:

```
airflow[19435]: app = cached_app_rbac(None) if settings.RBAC else cached_app(None)
airflow[19435]: File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 204, in cached_app
airflow[19435]: app = create_app(config, testing)
airflow[19435]: File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 186, in create_app
airflow[19435]: return app
airflow[19435]: File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 249, in __exit__
airflow[19435]: self.pop(exc_value)
airflow[19435]: File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 241, in pop
airflow[19435]: assert rv is self, "Popped wrong app context.  (%r instead of %r)" % (rv, self)
airflow[19435]: AssertionError: Popped wrong app context.  (<flask.ctx.AppContext object at 0x7fa117448d10> instead of <flask.ctx.AppContext object at 0x7fa18678f0d0>)
```

*app/**init**.py*

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import app.config as config

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_name)
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

*manage.py*

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
import app.config as config

from app import create_app, db

from app import models

app = create_app(config.Config)

app.app_context().push()

manager = Manager(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

@manager.command
def run():
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```